# How do I parse JSON dates with ActionScript?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, json, actionscript

I have dates in JSON which are generated from ASP.NET pages using the JSON.NET library. These dates look like this:

```
"LastModifiedDate": "\/Date(1301412877000-0400)\/"
```

How do I parse these with ActionScript from Flex 3 Professional? I'd like to have this in a native data format.

NOTE: What I'm not asking here is how do I parse a JSON feed with as3corelib. I have the JSON deserialized with that library but the dates are not decoded. That is why I need to know how to decode this date format.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)'s JSON implementation to decode your string into Objects.

Comment: That does not work. I should have stated that I use as3corelib to get the JSON. The JSON is properly bounded to my grid but the date is not decoded correctly. i

Comment: That's because the date you're using is non-standard.  as3corelib decodes [w3c DTF format (ISO 8601)](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).  You'll need to decode the string yourself into a Date if you want it to work or change your server's implementation of that date format.

Comment: Not according to the [JSON specs](http://www.json.org/). You'd be better off just sending a number over and since you already know it's a date, do the conversion client side with the timestamp with `new Date(timestamp)`.

Comment: OK I found http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx too. Looks like the ASP.NET dev must update the converter used.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP I use this function to get a Json date

```
 public static double JsonTime(DateTime dt)
    {//Convert datetime to a Json Datetime
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        DateTime d2 = dt.ToUniversalTime();
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);
        return Math.Round( ts.TotalMilliseconds,0);
    }
```

and then in JavaScript I use:

```
if (data.indexOf("\/Date(")==7)
       return  new Date(+data.replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

to convert back to a date if that helps

You will also have fun with single and double quotes but for the life of me I can not find a decoder that works server side with Json strings on Net Framework 3!

if you use String ="\u0027" in your code then the string is already converted and in the end I wrote a function that about does the job using a loop.

```
string Padding = "000";
                for (int f = 1; f <= 256; f++)
                {
                    string Hex = "\\u" + Padding.Substring(0, 4 - f.ToString().Length) + f;
                    string Dec = "&#" + Int32.Parse(f.ToString(), NumberStyles.HexNumber) + ";";
                    HTML = HTML.Replace(Hex, Dec);
                }
                HTML = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HTML);
```

Bad I know but if you have a better answer then please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

```
    /**
     * Converts 'Unix tick' format JSON Date to AS3 Date instances.
     * Example json input: "{\"BarDate\":\"\/Date(1334672700000)\/\" }"
     * Example json input: "{\"BarDate\":\"\/Date(1334672700000+0000)\/\" }"
     *
     * @param json date from JSON 
     * @return Date if conversion possible and worked else null. 
     */
    public static function parseJSONUnixTickDateToDate(json:String):Date
    {
        var date:Date = null;
        if (json)
        {
            json = json.substring(json.indexOf("(") + 1, json.indexOf(")"));
            var arr:Array = json.split("+");
            date = new Date(Number(arr[0]));
        }
        return date;
    }
```